# bootstrap-datetimepicker inside django template , selected date not inserted into the Input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">Schedule
                    Message</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <!-- content goes here -->
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dtp_schedule" class="col-md-2 control-
                 label">Publish on :</label>
                        <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-
                             date-format="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss" data-link-
                             field="dtp_schedule">
                            <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text"
                                   value="" readonly>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon
                     glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon
                    glyphicon-th"></span></span>
                            <input type="hidden" id="dt_now" value="{% now 'Y-m-d
                    H:i' %}">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                <span id="txt_error_schedule" class="alert alert-danger
                hide text-center col-md-12 col-xs-12">Please select a
                 date.</span>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

[image]

**The form inside the modal-body where the datapicker is used.eventhough the datepicker window pops up the selected date time is not getting inserted into the field, and whenever the the "Schedule" button is clicked it shows please select a date error**

Code for the datetimepicker :

```
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        //language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        showMeridian: 1,
        startDate: $('#dt_now').val(),
    });
```

Code for the button id function that gets invoked submission of the date

```
$('#btnSchedule').on('click', function(){

        if ($('#dtp_schedule').val() === ''){
            $('#txt_error_schedule').removeClass('hide');
            return ;
        }else{
            $('#txt_error_schedule').addClass('hide');
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
            var devices = getSelectedDevices();
            var data = $('#gcmForm').serialize()+'&'+$.param({ 'device_ids': devices });
                $.post("request/schedule/", data, function (response) {
                    window.location.href = '';
                }).fail(function() {
                      $('#btnSchedule').toggleClass('disabled');
                    alert( "error" );
                  });
        }
   });
```

CSS orders -->

```
{% block bootstrap-css %}
{{ block.super }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dashboard/libs/jquery/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dashboard/css/font.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dashboard/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-07I2e+7D8p6he1SIM+1twR5TIrhUQn9+I6yjqD53JQjFiMf8EtC93ty0/5vJTZGF8aAocvHYNEDJajGdNx1IsQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dashboard/css/app.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dashboard/css/autocomplete.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dashboard/css/custom.css' %}" type="text/css"/>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: show your datepicker function

Comment: have you tried the answer

Comment: yep but it still the same

Comment: can you post your css orders?

Comment: @Exprator Edited